# Content access based on the content author's role

Tags: 7, users

I have a content type named "Files". I have given access for users with roles `editor 1`, `editor 2` and `editor 3` to `update` and `delete` their own content.

Now If a user with *editor 1 creates a files content*. I need to allow other users with same role (editor 1) to update and delete the content.

I tried [Content Access Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) but it doesn't helps.

Can anyone give me a working example for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission on "own content" is connected to the node's author's uid and only relates to role in that a user with the role holding that permission can edit a node they created.

How I would solve your use case is with a hook_node_access in a custom module.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7
WARNING: I just threw this together as an example, I did not test, and you need to put in the right role values.

```
hook_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if( $op !== 'update'){
    // not my use-case
    return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
  }

  $author = user_load($node->uid);
  if( in_array( 'role1', $author->roles) && in_array( 'role1', $account->roles) ) {
    // the user editing has the same role as the author
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
  }
  // repeat ... etc.

  // we did not find what we were looking for, continue with normal access check
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (together with the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module you already have) you can get this to work ... The rule to create in this case woud be a variation of what's described in [Tutorial: editorial workflow with rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1027546) (within the paragraph "Create rules to publish the content").

In this case, the "action" would be to "Grant access by role".